# Send An Email Through Gmail Without JavaMail

Tags: java, email, gmail

I would like to send a notification with my java plugin for Bukkit (A Minecraft Modification Platform) It would be easiest to send this notification through a gmail account.

I am having trouble getting JavaMail to work correctly with bukkit, it works fine in a stand-alone program. I also don't know if it is against the license terms to package it with my plugin.

So I would like to be able to send an email through Gmail without the JavaMail API.
As you may know, Gmail requires either an SSL connection or a TLS connection.

OUTPUT:

```
220-moai.tallduck.com ESMTP Exim 4.69 #1 Mon, 05 Mar 2012 22:14:02 -0700 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.  
250-moai.tallduck.com Hello pool-CENSORED.cncdnh.fast.myfairpoint.net [CENSORED]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
334 CENSORED
334 CENSORED
235 Authentication succeeded
250 OK
500 unrecognized command
250 Accepted
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
250 OK id=1S4mio-0001VV-PB
221 moai.tallduck.com closing connection
Done.
```

The message does send, except the sender and recipient is blank.

Comment: You can use JavaMail. No reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can send the message direct using socket, for example:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SendingEmailUsingSocket {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int port = 25; 
                String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                try {           
                        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port); 

                        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
                        String username = encoder.encode("wajdyessam@gmail.com".getBytes());
                        String password = encoder.encode("yourpassword".getBytes());

                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                        dos.writeBytes("HELO\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("AUTH LOGIN");
                        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes(username);
                        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes(password);
                        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("MAIL FROM:<wajdyessam@hotmail.com>\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("RCPT TO: <wajdyessam@gmail.com>\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("DATA\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("Subject: Email test\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("Test 1 2 3");
                        dos.writeBytes("\r\n.\r\n");
                        dos.writeBytes("QUIT\r\n");

                        dos.flush();

                        String responseline;
                        while((responseline = is.readLine())!=null) {
                                System.out.println(responseline);
                        }

                        is.close();
                        dos.close( );                  
                        socket.close( );
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.err.println(ex);
                }
        }
}
```

notes:
username and password should be encoded using Base64, i use deprecated methods but feel free to use other way like: Base64 encoding in Apache Commons library.

username, password, subject, from and to are hard-coded, you should pass string there if you want generic method.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it a little bit though, In order to get rid of the depreciated method I did this. Replaced `DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` With: `DataInputStream isDI = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isDI));`

Comment: Also, the Base64 encoding did not work for me, so I used a Base64 class from [http://www.source-code.biz](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/)

Comment: I can't test it from where I am, because the Network Admins blocked all the ports except 80. So I will mark it as the correct answer once I get the chance to test it.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work correctly, I decided to try to use it with my own email server, but when the email sends and I retrieve it from the spam folder in gmail, the sender and recipient are both blank! I don't know how to fix this...

Comment: Updated my original question with my output, it would be great if you could help

Answer (score 1):

Better still you could use the [Apache Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) API. This allows you to define HTML emails and stuff with attachments too. Even better is the fact that it is tried and tested. This is the method used in my plugin, CommandsEX, so it definitely works within Bukkit!

You can take a look at how that works over at our GitHub repo. The exact class can be found [here](https://github.com/CommandsEX/Minecraft-CommandsEX/blob/master/CommandsEX/src/com/github/zathrus_writer/commandsex/helpers/Email.java).

Comment: OP specifically mentioned without JavaMail. Apache Email still uses JavaMail under the hood.

Comment: @BennyBottema Thanks for your comment. OP said that they struggled to get JavaMail to work with Bukkit. My suggestion comes from direct experience sending emails through Bukkit and it doesn't explicitly use JavaMail. I assumed he had trouble with the API and suggested a simpler, tried-and-tested way.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i used for an application i made for a company. (requires [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60916534/lib/javax.mail.jar))

#### vars

```
    private String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    private String FROM_ADDRESS = "######@gmail.com"; 
    private String FROM_PASSWORD = "########";
    private String TO_ADDRESS = "###############";
    private String FROM_NAME = "VDRS Lictor Training Application Emailer"; 
    private Properties props = new Properties();
```

#### in some method, create the proporties

```
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.user",FROM_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
```

#### when you need to send

this is the actual code i used. please modify it to your needs.

```
try{
      JButton b = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
      //button animation
      b.setText("Submitting Application...");
      //get values
      String player = name.getText();
      //make the message
      String msg = "<title>New Lictor Training Application from: " + player + "</title> \n";
      msg+="<h3>[Name]: </h3>" + player + "\n";
      msg+="<h3>[BR]: </h3>" + spinner.getValue() + "\n";
      msg+="<h3>[Platoon Leading Experience]: </h3>" + ((JLabel)    slider.getLabelTable().get(slider.getValue())).getText() + "\n";
      String time = timeEditor.getTextField().getText();
      String[] a = time.split(":");
      int hours = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
      int min = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
      calander.getDate().setHours(hours);
      calander.getDate().setMinutes(min);
      calander.getDate().setSeconds(00);
      msg+="<h3>[Date/Time]: </h3>" +  calander.getDate().toGMTString()+"\n";
      msg+="<h3>[Email]: </h3>" + email.getText();
      //set up email
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new AuthorizeEmail()); 
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
      try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM_ADDRESS));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO_ADDRESS));
        message.setSubject("New Outfit Application from: " + player);
        message.setContent(msg, "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
        b.setText("Application Submitted!");
    } catch (MessagingException e) 
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed sending application, please try again later.");
        b.setText("Submit Application");
    }


}catch(NullPointerException e)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed sending application.\n Did you fill out all the fields?.");
      submit.setText("Submit Application");
   }
```

#### you will also need this

```
class AuthorizeEmail extends Authenticator { 
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
        return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM_ADDRESS, FROM_PASSWORD); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Op specifically mentioned without JavaMail. Your example uses JavaMail directly.